# Application onCreate not being called in test

Tags: android

I am attempting to run my android tests using the AndroidJUnitRunner via the command "gradle connectedDebugAndroidTests" and I noticed that when my tests run, my app's Application object is not being created and "onCreate" is not being called.  I am guessing this is expected.  However, my tests rely on this code being invoked before the tests can run.

Is there a way to get this to happen?

I tried creating a new manifest in the "androidTest" section of my app that defines the "application" attribute, but this doesn't seem to work either :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp">

<application
    android:name=".MyTestApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a method annotated with @Before and in that method do below code to start your application class :

```
@Before
public void prepareApplication() {
    MyTestApplication app = (MyTestApplication) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
    app.onCreate();
}
```